# Swapping selichot of the fourth and fifth days after Rosh HaShanah

Tags: minhag, selichot

I’ve noticed that some Ashkenazi communities (including those following *minhag lita* and *minhag polin*) will sometimes swap the order of which days of *selichot* are said during the Aseret Yemei Teshuvah.

In a year when Yom Kippur falls on a Monday or a Thursday, they will recite the *selichot* printed for the ‘fifth day’ of the Aseret Yemei  Teshuvah the day before those printed for the ‘fourth day’ of the Aseret Yemei Teshuvah.

What is the reason for this custom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With full thanks and acknowledgement to @JoelK, it writes in Nitei Gavriel [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=63) the following:

> כשחל יוה"כ ביום ב' או ביום ה' יש מקדימים לומר סליחות של י"ג מדות ביום ב' או ביום ה' שלפניו, כדי שיאמרו הסליחות של י"ג מדות ביום שיש בו קרה"ת ויש מקומות שנוהגים אשר רק אם חל בשבת מקדימים ליום ה', אבל כשחל ביום אחר א"צ לשנות, ויש מקומות שאין משנים בשום ענין
> וכל מקום נוהג כמנהגו
>
> *When Yom Kippur falls on a Monday or a Thursday, some bring forward the selichos that we say of the 13 middos on the Monday or Thursday before, in order that these selichos of the 13 middos are said on a day in which there is Torah reading. And there are some places that are accustomed to do so only if [the day before Erev Yom Kippur] falls on shabbos then they bring these selichos forward to Thursday, but when it falls on another day, one does not need to change. And there are some places that don't change at all. In all instances, every place should do like their custom.*

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to say that particular poem on a day with Torah reading?

Comment: Good question?!

Comment: Here's what I heard from a Hasidic friend. Monday and Thursday are aligned with the sefirot of gvura and hod, both linked to din. To soft the impact of the din on those days, Chazal instituted Torah reading (since they never share the deep reasons, they called it "to avoid 3 days without Torah"). The minhag to say the slichot of 13 attributes is to further soften the din of these days cc: @DoubleAA